# VNC (tigervnc) via 'actual' ssh tunnel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling, vnc, tigervnc

I understand that vnc which is not encrypted or secure usually is used via an ssh tunnel. I currently have the native Ubuntu 20.04 VNC server (vino-server) working via an ssh tunnel. The ssh tunnel is my webserver which is in my living room. So via Remmina (vnc client) I ssh into my webserver and from there I ssh to my remote machine and can use Remmina/vino-server this way.

Unfortunately this setup has the disadvantage that as a resolution you always get whatever monitor is plugged into the remote machine. And if there is no monitor plugged, you get a black screen.

So I found out that tigervnc can open a remote Gnome session, you can scale it any which way you like. So I installed tigervnc and have it running as a vnc server now (closed vino-server). But I struggle to use Remmina as a VNC viewer, I just can't get it to work.

One problem is now that all across the internet it is described how to use an 'ssh tunnel' to your remote machine but really what most tutorials show you is how to ssh into your remote machine and then have VNC run over ssh. So, it's not really an ssh-tunnel in my understanding. And it's impossible to find how to use an 'actual' ssh tunnel to first ssh into my web server, then ssh into my remote machine and THEN stream VNC from there..

Can anyone point me towards ressources where I can find out how to ssh into my web server and from there ssh into my remote machine and have the VNC (tigervnc) connection be used this way? Terminal / Remmina / TigerVNC viewer / ... all is usable to me, as long as I can use an ssh tunnel.

Additional information: My local machine is Ubuntu 20.04, my webserver is a headless Raspi4 Raspbian server and my remote machine is a Ubuntu 20.04 as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit confused, but I don't blame you, it's all pretty complex.

> One problem is now that all across the internet it is described how to use an 'ssh tunnel' to your remote machine but really what most tutorials show you is how to ssh into your remote machine and then have VNC run over ssh.

Well running "VNC over ssh" is the actual act of tunneling you are asking about: usually you redirect some local port to remote port behind ssh server (on same machine or other internal machine further down the netwrok) and connect to local port to tunnel given VNC traffic to remote machine that way. Does my explanantion make sense?